The origin of NaN in the dataset
I train on a dataset with Kaggle from Netflix, where information about the series is provided. I am interested in a question about NaN in the column with the name Director. I want to try to understand if these zeros are specially made for stimulation or if the absence of a director is really the norm, judging by the histogram. Is it worth focusing on the NaN data or not?
code
checking the value where the director is missing

df[df['director'].isna()]['release_year'].hist()


I tried to search for directors in Google for series whose directors are absent, judging by the dataset. How correct is this? I understand that these questions may seem silly. It's just that I'm just starting to dive into this area :)
